# identifying highlight colors on footer

Tags: color-theory, color-profile

hey guys have a look at the footer interface below ,

[image]

its a bit unique because the footer has a white background and then each heading had a unique color (orange , blue , green , pink) , obviously the colors serve as the heightlight colors and the focus is brought to the footer headings .

now what i'd like to know is ,

what would these colors be classified as ? , i mean specific to this footer , what can the heading colors (orange , blue , green , pink) be classified as ?

for example there are hot colors , rainbow colors , cool colors etc , so what are these set of colors used on the footer ? do they have some kind of a classification ? i was just wondering and curious.

Comment: I don't think there's a direct "classification".

Comment: @Scott Hi there , well i guess the designer/dev did not randomly choose the colors , there must have been some decision on the color pallet , hmmm i just google funky colors and found something similar http://www.colorschemer.com/schemes/viewscheme.php?id=6291 .

Comment: Not all palettes have a basis in some predetermined formula. Often they are just what "looks good". http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54801/what-is-the-process-for-creating-a-color-palette-like-this/54917#54917